# Show some text with a button - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have some hidden text in HTML that I want to show when I click on a button but at the same time I want that button generates the code behind in C#

I used this code to create the JavaScript function

```
function toggle() {

var ele = document.getElementById("dpt");
var text = document.getElementById("Button1");
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
```

and this is the text and button in html

```
        <td id="dpt" style="display: none"> <b>Dias previstos de trabalho:</b> <asp:Label ID="Lbl_DiasTrab" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
    <td id= "md" style="display: none"> <b>Media Diária:</b> <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Media" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td id= "nrmed" style="display: none"> <b>Número de Médicos:</b> <asp:Label ID="LblNrMedicos" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    <td id= "indcob" style="display: none"> <b>Índice de Cobertura:</b> <asp:Label ID="LblIndCob" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Ver"  Width="74px" Height="30px" />
```

Meanwhile I did it but When i click on the button it refreshes the page

I used this code on html

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"  OnClientClick="toggle()" Text="Ver"  Width="74px" Height="30px" />
```

Comment: You'll need to inspect your element. Code behind is probably adding something like "MainContentPlaceholder_YOURID" before the ID of the element.

Answer (score 0):

@Press is right, your ID will be modified server-side before it's sent to the client. Instead, pass `this` to `toggle`, and it will be a reference to your button:

**JavaScript:**

```
function toggle(text) {

    var ele = document.getElementById("dpt");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "show";
    }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "hide";
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<td id="dpt" style="display: none"> <b>Dias previstos de trabalho:</b> <asp:Label ID="Lbl_DiasTrab" runat="server"></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>
<td id= "md" style="display: none"> <b>Media Diária:</b> <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Media" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
<td id= "nrmed" style="display: none"> <b>Número de Médicos:</b> <asp:Label ID="LblNrMedicos" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
<td id= "indcob" style="display: none"> <b>Índice de Cobertura:</b> <asp:Label ID="LblIndCob" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click"  OnClientClick="toggle(this)" Text="Ver"  Width="74px" Height="30px" />
```

Comment: I didn't understand sorry

Comment: @MaraPimentel I updated the code to show the complete example.

Comment: @MaraPimentel So you only want the button to call the `toggle` method and nothing else? I ask because you have the `onclick="Button1_Click"` attribute as well.

Comment: I said that I want is the Button1 to call the onclick="Button1_Click" and the  OnClientClick="toggle(this) at the same time when I click on Button1. I want to call some code behind on Button1_Click and call the javascript function

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood. A server-side click handler requires the page to be submitted (refreshed) in order to fire the event. If you want to fire server-side code without a page refresh, you should look into using AJAX. There are limitless resources on the web that can assist you with that.

Comment: what I want to know is if I am doing something wrong because onclick="Button1_Click" attribute is working without problem, the OnClientClick="toggle(this) is making the html text reload everytime i click on Button1

Comment: @MaraPimentel So you're saying that when you have just the `onclick="Button1_Click"`, the page doesn't refresh (but it executes the `Button1_Click` event), but when you add `OnClientClick="toggle(this)"` it causes the page to refresh?